# Holding session title after spliting pane in iterm2

Tags: title, prompt, iterm2

I'd like to set a name for a tab, but in iterm2 there's only a session title.

It works fine when I have one split pane in a tab,

[image: set session titile]

but the session title will change after split the tab to two panes.

[image: after split]

Is there a way to write a script to hold the session title after spliting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by following applescript:

```
tell application "iTerm"
    tell current session of current window
        set nameOfSession to {get name} as text
        set newSession to {split horizontally with same profile}
        select newSession
        set name to nameOfSession
    end tell
end tell
```

Put it to `~/Library/Application Support/iTerm/Scripts`, restart iterm2 then you can see the script in `Script Menu` ([more about scripts](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-scripting.html)).

And may be you want to map a shortcut to execute the script in System Keyboard Shortcut settings.